# How to update a file of user names and passwords using PHP

Tags: php, file

I use a public domain url shortener called yourls which I have made changes to.
The php script uses a config file that users passwords and logins are stored in
which is config.php

The format for this file is various settings etc and then a section for the passwords and level of the user. Here is the section within the file I need to
work with.

```
 $yourls_user_passwords = array(
      'guest' =>    'phpass:!2a!08!evrztH.lysEouhMAai50MO1sl4/C234Q99HoL3jezyfZU4gMp95SG' /*  Password encrypted by YOURLS */ ,
      'chuckb' =>   'phpass:!2a!08!q53CY5Xp6rY7Nx65Jg98H2q9trxb8GYpAcz7in06b3Qk4G8vYrZ6' /* Password  encrypted by YOURLS */ ,
      'jimc' => 'phpass:!2a!08!q74CErXp6rY7Hx68egr8t2q9trxb9FYpFcz9in06b6Tk5e8vGrZ3' /* Password encrypted by YOURLS */ ,
// You can have one or more 'login'=>'password' lines
     );
 //** assign user role */

 $authmgr_role_assignment = array(
 'administrator' => array(
   'chuckb',

  ),
 'editor' => array(
   'jimc',

  ),
   'contributor' => array(
    'guest',    
   ),

   );
```

I would like to know how to using a php form add, new users to this list and delete existing ?

I also would like if possible the file to be readonly until this scrip updates it and then have it be made read only again if that is possible ?

I have never worked with php writing to a file.  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I sure hope you're protecting that file with 50 big locks on it and 20 pitbulls. Why not just use a database?

Comment: If you want to continue to have users stored in the file system I think the easiest solution would be to create a users.json file. Then in the script above load the json file and decode it. In the management script just load and decode the json file, and encode and save when you have made changes.

Comment: Examples of how to do this would be helpful and what I am looking for.
I understand I need to read the file in and somehow append new users to the area's above then write the file but have no idea on how to do that. I also would want the file permissions set to read only when done.